# Unsupported Media Type error in browser console when sending json using angularjs to spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, spring-mvc

Here is my controller function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logInChecker", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody String logInCheckerFn(@RequestBody UserLogData userLogData){
        Integer userAuthFlag = goAnalyserModel.checkUserAuth(userLogData);
        return userAuthFlag.toString();
    }
```

My Bean class

public class UserLogData {

```
private String userName;
private String password;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

My html file with angularjs function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="nameAppIndexPage">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Go Analyser - Login</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <!-- Le styles -->
      <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <style type="text/css">
         body {
         padding-top: 60px;
         padding-bottom: 40px;
         }
      </style>
      <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="nameController">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
               <a class="brand" href="#">Go Analyser</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Example row of columns -->
         <div class="row">
           <div class=" margin_alignment"></div>
            <div class="span4"></div>
            <div class="span4">
               <form class="form-signin">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                  <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="userName">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                  <!-- <center><button class="btn btn-large" type="submit">Login</button></center>-->

                  <button type="submit" ng-click='checkLogin()'>login</button>
               </form>

            </div>
            <div class="span4"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="hr_space"></div>
         <footer>
         </footer>
      </div>
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>


      <script>
                    var myApp = angular.module('nameAppIndexPage',[]);
                    myApp.controller('nameController',function($http,$scope){
                        $scope.checkLogin = function(){
                            alert("inside checklogin()");

                            var userName = $scope.userName;
                            var password = $scope.password;

                            var dataToSend = {
                                "userName" : userName,
                                "password" : password   
                            };
                            console.log(dataToSend);
                            alert("after data to send");  
                            $http.post('logInChecker',dataToSend).success(function(data){
                                if(data == 1){
                                    alert("inside loginSuccess");
                                }else{
                                    alert("username and password mismatch");
                                    //write function to show incorrect password
                                }
                            }).error(function(data){
                                alert("error in post" + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
                            });
                        }
                    });
               </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I keep getting unsupported media error in browser console. The angularjs function is not getting the request through to the spring controller. But every thing seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message happens either when the request cannot be converted to a java object, or when a java object cannot be converted to response.

As you've explained, you have the former case. Few things that you should check:

1. check that you have the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your servlet configuration
2. check that you have jackson dependencies on your classpath, for spring 4.x you should have the jackson 2.x version, for spring 3.x you should use jackson 1.9

to ensure that your response is also properly converted you should, besides having the proper dependencies, ensure that

1. Either an *Accept* header is sent with your request with the value `application/json` or that the *RequestMapping* annotation of your handler method has the attribute `produces = {"application/json"}`

Answer (score 0):

Add  @JsonProperty("**") (**Name of the property) to your bean class. Check in the browser's developer tool type of JSON post messages.